# Linq to Entity query String Id compare to integer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, linq-to-entities, azure-mobile-services

I'm developping a Mobile Service on Azure with .Net Backend.

I'm writing a Custom API to get values from database between ID's. For example get values between 3 - 50 Id's.

But I have a problem with string ID. MObile service is a form of MVC. My database created by my model named "New". "New" model class is child of "EntityData" of course. So New model class get "Id" row from "EntityData". In "EntityData" class, Id row is string.

I want to get datas from database between Id's but database has string format Id row. How can I get values?

```
birfincankafeinService.Models.birfincankafeinContext context = new Models.birfincankafeinContext();
var queryResults = context.News.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Id)
.Where(x=> int.Parse(x.Id) > startId && int.Parse(x.Id) < endId ).ToList();
```

Here is my exception:

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32
>   Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store"

How can I get datas from database between Id's? I can not do it because "EntityData" class has Id type of string.

Answer (score 0):

There is a SqlFunctions class that exposes several of SQL Server's T-SQL based functions to use in EF queries. Unfortunately the CAST and CONVERT statements are not exposed. The best option you have at the moment is to implement a stored procedure that does the filtering you require and returns a full representation of the News object.

Alternatively, if you don't have a whole lot of data you can return all the data to the client side at which point you can use the .NET functions such as:

```
var queryResults = context.News.ToList().Where(x=> int.Parse(x.Id) > startId && int.Parse(x.Id) < endId );
```

Answer (score -1):

When The DB field is int. 
You can directly compare integers.    a < b.

**You need to parse the String to int BEFORE using it in the Linq to entities Expression.**
So an Int value is used in the comparison. You cant have an embedded call to int.parse in EF.

```
birfincankafeinService.Models.birfincankafeinContext context 
            = new   Models.birfincankafeinContext();
var idAsInt = int.Parse(x.Id);
var queryResults = context.News.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Id)
      .Where(x=> idAsInt) > startId && idAsInt < endId ).ToList();
```

Comment: x is not a local variable. x is function's variable. x assigns database's Id row in my code